# Formatting date 2018-04-03T14:10:00-07:00 to any readable date/time in Python

Tags: python, django, date

2018-04-03T14:10:00-07:00 is there a built in python method? Or something in Django? I am only used to working with javascript/node and I can't figure this out

Comment: Check out the datetime library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: How's the weather in the mountain time zone?

Comment: @EliotK that doesn't handle the timezone offset.

Comment: It does, you just need to tell it where the timezone is

Answer (score 1):

Please try the code below:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

parse('2018-04-03T14:10:00-07:00').strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%f')
```

Output

> > > '03-04-2018 14:10:000000'

You can pass the specific format you want out of the date.
for reference please go to this document:
[Strftime options](http://strftime.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any specific single function to handle that format, but tweaking the text a little and using a custom format will get you what you need.

```
from datetime import datetime 
txt = "2018-04-03T14:10:00-07:00"
txtfmt = txt[:10]+ " " + txt[11:19] + " " + txt[19:22] + txt[-2:]
dt = datetime.strptime(txtfmt,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [Arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) a try.

```
>>> import arrow
>>> d = arrow.get('2018-04-03T14:10:00-07:00')
>>> d
<Arrow [2018-04-03T14:10:00-07:00]>
>>> d.humanize()
'3 hours ago'
>>> d.format()
'2018-04-03 14:10:00-07:00'
>>>
```

For Django you can use it with [django-arrow-field](https://github.com/gizmag/django-arrow-field) for easier access.